# Setter Property Required primitive dependency is not explicitly defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, structuremap

I have Asp.Net MVC Application and I have used structuremap, 
I use custom ThrottleAttribute ActionFilter.
follow [rate limiting in asp.net mvc](https://www.shieldui.com/blogs/rate-limiting-in-asp-net-mvc)

```
public enum TimeUnit
{
    Minute = 60,
    Hour = 3600,
    Day = 86400
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class ThrottleAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public TimeUnit Time { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var seconds = Convert.ToInt32(Time);

        var key = string.Join(
            "-",
            seconds,
            filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod,
            filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName,
            filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName,
            filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress
        );

        // increment the cache value
        var cnt = 1;
        if (HttpRuntime.Cache[key] != null)
        {
            cnt = (int)HttpRuntime.Cache[key] + 1;
        }
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(
            key,
            cnt,
            null,
            DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(seconds),
            Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
            CacheItemPriority.Low,
            null
        );

        if (cnt >= Count)
        {

            filterContext.Result = new ContentResult
            {
                Content = "You are allowed to make only " + Count + " requests per " + Time.ToString().ToLower()
            };
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 429;
        }
    }
}
```

after I use ThrottleAttribute throw Exception:

> Setter Property 'Time' (ActionFilters.TimeUnit): Required primitive dependency is not explicitly defined

And my ActionFilter Registry:

```
public class ActionFilterRegisteryClass : StructureMap.Registry
{
    public ActionFilterRegisteryClass(Func<StructureMap.IContainer> containerFactory)
    {
        For<IFilterProvider>().Use(
            new StructurMapFilterProvider(containerFactory));

        Policies.SetAllProperties(x =>
        {
            x.Matching(p =>
                p.DeclaringType.CanBeCastTo(typeof(ActionFilterAttribute)) &&
                (
                    p.DeclaringType.Namespace.StartsWith("MyNamespace")
                ) &&
                !p.PropertyType.IsPrimitive &&
                p.PropertyType != typeof(string)
                );
        });
    }
}
```

Exception is fire in:     container.BuildUp(filter.Instance);

```
public class StructurMapFilterProvider : FilterAttributeFilterProvider
{
    private readonly Func<StructureMap.IContainer> _Container;

    public StructurMapFilterProvider(Func<StructureMap.IContainer> container)
    {
        _Container = container;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext,
        ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        var filters = base.GetFilters(controllerContext, actionDescriptor);

        var container = _Container();

        foreach (var filter in filters)
        {
            container.BuildUp(filter.Instance);

            yield return filter;
        }
    }
}
```

> Setter Property 'Time' (ActionFilters.TimeUnit): Required primitive dependency is not explicitly defined

What should I do?

How explicitly defined PrimitiveTypes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in Registering ActionFilterClass in structuremap. I have changed it as follows:

```
public class ActionFilterRegisteryClass : StructureMap.Registry
{
    public ActionFilterRegisteryClass(Func<StructureMap.IContainer> containerFactory)
    {
        For<IFilterProvider>().Use(
            new StructurMapFilterProvider(containerFactory));

        Policies.SetAllProperties(x =>
        {
            x.Matching(p =>
                p.DeclaringType.CanBeCastTo(
                !p.PropertyType.IsPrimitive &&
                !p.PropertyType.IsEnum &&
                p.PropertyType != typeof(string));
        });
    }
}
```